# Como eu posso melhorar este loop que tem um foreach dentro de outro?

Tags: php, loop, foreach

Estou fazendo este código que tem 2 **foreach's** e carrega 350 imóveis com mais ou menos **3500 links de imagens**, na verdade não chamei as fotos, só os links, isso tudo carrega em **meio segundo**.

A variável `$array` armazena conteúdo de um **[XML](http://tecnologia.axitech.com.br/xml/xml_vivareal.xml)**. Dentro desse XML tem várias informações inclusive arrays de informações como **Media** que armazena todas as imagens do imóvel.

No caso abaixo, o segundo `array` pega `$imovel->Media->Item` e faz uma listagem das fotos que estão no imóvel.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml_vivareal.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$array = $xml->Listings->Listing;
$number = 1;

foreach ($array as $imovel) {
    echo $number++ ." - ". $imovel->ListingID . "<br>";
    echo $imovel->Title . "<br>";

    foreach ($imovel->Media->Item as $fotos) {
        echo $fotos . "<br>";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

> **Resultado produzido**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acho que não pois suas imagens trazem  registros múltiplos de outro objeto

Comment: @MarcosBrinner então qier dizer que os dois foreachs dessa forma estão corretos.

Comment: [Veja isso.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Não há problema em usar um loop dentro de outro. Uma coisa que vc pode fazer pra melhorar **a entrega dos dados** é criar um buffer (`ob_start()`/`ob_end_flush()`) pra entregar tudo de uma única vez pro navegador. Talvez "aparente mais desempenho". 
@EmersonBarcellos acho que não é válido pra esse caso, uma vez que `$imovel->Media->Item` é da `array` do primeiro loop.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira alternativa é armazenando o conteúdo HTML e imprimir (echo) tudo no final, podendo assim usar a função **implode** no lugar do **foreach** interno.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml_vivareal.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$array = $xml->Listings->Listing;
$number = 1;
$html = '';

foreach ($array as $imovel) {
    $html .= $number++ ." - ". $imovel->ListingID . "<br>";
    $html .= $imovel->Title . "<br>";

    $html .= implode("<br>", $imovel->Media->Item);

    $html .= "<br>";
}

echo $html;

?>
```

Acredito que dessa maneira o código fique mais limpo e elegante. Com relação à performance, seria bom que você fizesse um teste nas duas versões e postasse o resultado.